# Open Source websites

Tags: php, html, css, web

I am teaching myself web development, and right now I'm using HTML/CSS/PHP, but I am having difficulty understanding how the code for sites should be structured to avoid lots of repeat code and things like that.

I was wondering if there were some slightly complex websites that were open source, so I could view all the code (including the php) to see how things are actually done so I can create websites properly by example of these opensource sites.

Comment: your best bet is too learn about how to use open source web frameworks like Zend Framework or Codeigniter. They use an MVC-ish pattern to build web apps/sites. you will have to first study up on classes and autoloaders however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're considering to use MVC paradigm, I would suggest you to study how a web framework is designed and implemented (such as [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), ror or [zend](http://framework.zend.com/)), in order to learn how a big web app is structured (requests, security, cache, logins, database, forms, etc...) and then try to design and build your own one.

This will teach you a lot of valuable concepts such as:

- How MVC works (Controller->Model->View)
- Application Bootstrap (Single Entry Point)
- Directory Structures
- Database Access Layers (ORM, DAO, Abstract Factory)
- Session Handling
- Form creation (forms, decorators, validators)
- Cache implementations and benefits
- Helpers
- Routing (friendly url's)

If you design your own framework propperly you'll have a base structure for all your web apps, and a lot of classes for common functionalities ready to use on your site (login, forms, html, etcetera).

You don't have to implement everything, you can use some libraries for the most complex tasks. Such as Propel or Doctrine for the ORM, or APC for the cache system, or PDO for database access, or apache mod_rewrite for rewriting urls.

I did this and learnt a lot about how to make decent web app.

Comment: i also believe it will also help you improve your coding style. hope this helps

Comment: you can also check Content Management Systems such as wordpress, drupal, joomla, etc..

Answer (score 1):

[**SourceForge**](http://sourceforge.net/) is a website that lists millions of open-source projects free for you to use and download.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Q&A system [OSQA.net](http://www.osqa.net/download/), it's similar to StackExchange QA sites, but opensource

StackOverflow (StackExchange powered QA system) is not opensource itself, info here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available